# google maps javascript SDK InfoWindow not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to show the `InfoWindow` class from the Google maps SDK without much success. Note that I am logging the instance I am creating and I can see it's indeed exist. Only when I try to call it using the `open` method, nothing seems to show.

```js
  static drawExistingPolygons(polygons, cb) {
    for (const coords of polygons) {
      console.log({ coords });
      const polygon = new this.MapInstance.maps.Polygon({
        path: coords,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.15,
        map: this.MapInstance.map,
        editable: true,
        geodesic: true,
        draggable: true
      });
      const infowindow = new this.MapInstance.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
      });

      polygon.addListener("click", e => {
        console.log(e);
        if (cb) {
          cb(e);
        }
        console.log(infowindow); // log the created instance of InfoWindow
        infowindow.open(this.MapInstance.map, polygon);
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The `InfoWindow` class expect an optional [`InfoWindowOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.zIndex) object, there you can see there is an option to set `position` , set it to the `latLng` of the marker (or the position where you want the to show). And it will work